Onwards and Upwards, or maybe Downwards
Ages ago now, Overly Sarcastic Productions released a video on Dante's Inferno, and in it Red said the iconic line "Onwards and upwards, or maybe downwards" in reference to Dante and Virgil's descent. It has been living rent free in my head ever since.
Today, I stumbled upon this question about suitable translations for "Onwards and Upwards", and now I must know: What about "or maybe downwards"?
The currently only answer to the linked question is "prorsum et sursum", which has a suitable lilt to it, reminiscent of "onwards and upwards" itself in English. I know that 'or' could be 'vel' or 'aut', and some searching has told me that a tentative translation of "Onwards and Upwards, or maybe Downwards" would be

Prorsum et Sursum, aut fortasse Deorsum

Does that make any sense?

I'd recommend using aut rather than vel for your purposes, but in either case, I think fortasse deorsum works fine. (Lose the capital D.)

@Figulus Thank you for pointing me in the direction of aut, I have adjusted my question accordingly. Also, I'm translating the case through - deorsum was capitalized simply because downwards was capitalized.

My suggestion is nisi forte. It has 336 hits in the PHI corpus and is mentioned explicitly in the L&S entry for nisi:

In transitions; also in the combinations nisi vero, nisi forte, nisi tamen, unless perhaps, etc., mostly ironical.

The "mostly ironical" meaning seems to fit the bill for your use case.
This yields:

Prorsum et Sursum, nisi forte Deorsum

Some other options:

aut forte (14 hits)
vel forte (6 hits)

I also don't disagree with the two suggestions by @cmw, though they seem to be less common:

vel fortassis/e (only 1 hit)
aut fortassis/e (8 hits)


Yes, this is much better. Removing my answer completely because I was more focused on vel v. aut, but this is the way to go.

@cmw Now I'm curious what it was. I never got a chance to see it

@NoName I didn't really go into detail about it, but I suggested aut fortasse wasn't wrong. However, I went more into why vel would have been preferable to aut given the circumstances. But since nisi forte is the established idiom, I'd recommend going with that instead.
